# Oracle Apex 5.1: Report column based on LOV(List of values) showing returned value not display value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an interactive report with a form. In the form I have two select lists. The first select list is a list of values defined in the shared component. And the second select list is another list of values which is also defined in the shared component but this select list populates its LOV based on the selected item in the first select list.

Let the names of the select lists are:

1. Region.
2. Country(which is dependent on the selected item in Region field).

Now when I press save/create button in the form, a row is created in the report. The Region column and Country column in the report are both "Plain Text(based on List of Values)". But what I see is the Region column is showing the correct display value of the LOV but the Country column is showing the returned value of the LOV.

I want both of these columns show the display values rather than the returned value. Could anyone help me find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same LOVs in form and interactive report? If so and in the conditional LOV (countries) you refer your form item (ex. PX_REGION) it will not work correctly in IR. Probably IR is showing the returned value because the option "show extra values" is checked.

If this is the case my suggestion is to change your IR and instead of a "Plain Text(based on List of Values)" you make it plain text and change the query to an inline query in IR query to obtain the value you want to show.

If you don't want/like to put your LOV queries in different places I suggest you to use [this approach shared by Nick Buytaert](https://apexplained.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/manage-your-lovs-in-plsql/)

Hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: You are correct @hmarques. I was using the same LOV in the Form and the IR which was creating the problem. I have read your link which is very useful when I need multiple conditional LOV in forms. But I cannot understand how I would refer the column of the report to pass the column value as parameter. 
For now, I have created another LOV which lists all Countries and referenced it from the corresponding column in the report. 
Thanks for your great help.

Comment: The shared link is useful when you want to use conditional LOVs in multiple pages not to use in queries. You IR query you can use an inline query or create a function to return the description value of the field you want, something like this 
    FUNCTION f_get_country (p_id IN country_table.id%TYPE)
    RETURN country_table.desc%TYPE AS
        v_country_desc country_table.desc%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT desc into v_country_desc from country_table where id = p_id;
        return v_country_desc;
    END fun_get_languages;

note: an inline query would have better performance.